# Wordpress / jQuery Hover Effect for Posts or Images in Same Category

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, categories

I've got a WP portfolio site using isotope to filter and sort.  It works well; however, one thing I want to do is just not working.

When I hover over an image on the portfolio page, I want it to highlight all other images that are in that category.  I can do it by adding each category manually using jQuery.  The person whose portfolio it will be will be adding a lot more categories and won't be able to go in and fiddle with the .js file every time he adds something.

I'm sure there's a way,  I just don't know how to write code.  I've got this and it works nicely, but I'd rather it be able to work dynamically and not have to define the category specifically.

```
    $('.portfolio_categories-mood-images').bind('hover', function(e){
    $('.portfolio_categories-mood-images').each(function(i){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight-all');
    }, function() { $(this).removeClass('highlight-all'); }); });
```

I'm not sure if I'm making sense.  I'm still fairly new with jQuery and Javascript, so thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: In your example is `mood` and `images` each a category?

Comment: You should not have tagged this with wordpress or php. Only tag with what your issue is.

Comment: See if what I have rewritten in my **"REDO"** is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REDO:**

Based on your response regarding what your `<div>` code looks like per image, see if this revision works better. I have notated for clarity:

```
<script>
// Use a more general selection type that will grab portfolio images
$(".portfolio_item").hover(
function() {
    // Get the data contained in category
    var ThisData    =   $(this).data('category');
    // Split it with spaces since there are multiple space-separated tags
    var GetClass    =   ThisData.split(" ");
    // Since you have same-name classes as the array value 0 (presumably)
    // you can just use the category value 0 for class name
    $("."+GetClass[0]).addClass('highlight-all');
},
function() {
    // Just remove the class from all elements
    $(".portfolio_item").removeClass('highlight-all');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is close.  Each of the posts has an attribute of data-category.  None of them are undefined, though.  I think what I need has to be ThisData is ThisData or something like that.

Comment: Yeah undefined would be called if you have images on your page that are part of the layout of your site. They would be undefined. Otherwise, you will have all images on the page have this rollover effect

Comment: What do the images look like (you said they contain a `data` already)? Can you provide an example of that code for those images?

Comment: Here is an example of the output of one of the posts on the page.  The category in this instance is "mood images":  <div id="post-4097" class="_mood-images portfolio_item layout_square post-4097 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry portfolio_categories-mood-images isotope-item" data-id="" data-category="_mood-images portfolio_item layout_square" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate(460px, 250px);">

Comment: WOW!  That's perfect @Rasclatt.  Thank you so much for your help.  I wish I could do more than just check the little checkmark "answered" for you.